# HTML/JavaScript Script Injection Exception

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception

I tried to write a bookmarklet which depends on another script. For this my bookmarklet includes a function like this:

```
function load(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.onload = callback;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

The callback function is called on most pages, but on some pages I get the following exception in the console and the script is not loaded (facebook.com is one example).

> Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)

An example of a bookmarklet:

> javascript:function%20load(url,callback){var%20script=document.createElement('script');script.type='text/javascript';script.src=url;script.onload=callback;document.head.appendChild(script);}load('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',function(){console.log('Loaded');})

I use FireFox 29 on Ubuntu 12.04. If it is executed a "Loaded" should a appear in the console. On the first load an additional access to the resource is visible in the console. But as written above on e.g. facebook.com nothing happens at all. Neither is the script loaded nor is the callback called.

Comment: "Some pages"? Which pages? If we were going to reproduce this issue, what would we have to do?

Comment: Where it happens was written in my question before. I've added a boorkmarklet with the the same code below.

Comment: So how do we reproduce this issue? Write out the steps for us so that we can reproduce it. As it's written, you've given us a script, and said, "This doesn't work" -- that doesn't help us. We need to be able to go through the steps you're going through. So what are those steps? (Please edit this into your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite likely due to XSS from the bookmarklet itself. FF 35.0 doesn't have an error anymore and shows a well formatted message.